# Forcing windows to wait for a service to stop when it is shutting down

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I'm having an issue that I can't figure out regarding a Windows Service I have written in C#.  What I am trying to do is wait for a specified period for a child process to terminate before I am forced to kill it and stop the service.  I have set my timeout for anywhere from 5 to 15 seconds and my service waits the appropriate amount of time and then kills the child and stops when I stop it via the mmc service window.  However if I shutdown the computer my service gets blown away before it is able to wait and stop properly.  I have read that Windows allows for a timeout of 30 seconds for a service to shutdown before it blows it away.  My code is executing in much less time than 30 seconds, max is around 20 seconds or so, depending on what I set the timeout at.

I have tried using the SetServiceStatus() function in the win32 Api but it has not changed the function of the code.  I have verified that the function call is succeeding.  Is there any other way to force Windows to wait for my service to shutdown properly?  I am testing it in Windows 7 x86, and Windows Vista Sp1 x86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows will **not** let any service prevent shutdown, this is by-design. as Gyuri says, you have to consider a different design for your app.

Comment: +1: *Obviously* the solution here is making the service take less time to stop. Soooo many applications ignore the importance of this and.

Answer (score 1):

This is a global Windows setting, apparently: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305788. I would be worried if I had to rely on the users to let my service shut down. I would save my data periodically instead.

Comment: This sucks. I have a windows service hosting virtual machines that take time to shutdown. I don't want it to wait indefintely, but a longer timeout (little over a minute) would ensure my machines are properly shut down.

Answer (score 0):

OnSTart and OnSTop are inherited from a base class which does quite a bit for you.  All your implementations of these methods should do is start or stop your client code, windows will do the rest.

I'll caveat this with the fact that I use C# and .Net's implementation of ServiceBase does this, I cannot talk authoritatively about C/C++ code or APIs.